# vba excel : runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having  the error "runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed" when I launched the following macro :

```
Dim nameDebut As Range, nameFin As Range ' <- my global variable
sub mySub()
...
   Set nameDebut = Range("A1").Offset(0, 1)
   Set nameFin = Range("A1").Offset(0, 20)
   Range("nameDebut:nameFin").Select ' <- fail occurs here
...
```

So I would like to select this range of cells like this. Is it possible ? Any workaround ?

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the last line to

```
Range(nameDebut,nameFin).Select
```

Not discussing your code, but using `select` is nearly never needed in VBA. Maybe this can help:

```
dim myRange as Range
set myRange = Range(nameDebut,nameFin)
' Now use `myRange` for whatever you want to do...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Does it work with that `Select` on the end?  Shouldn't it just be `set myRange = Range(nameDebut,nameFin)` .... remembering to fully qualify the range reference as well.

Comment: For more detail on avoiding `Select`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba